# Does the plane $x_3 = 1$ contain any periodic solutions?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

I am studying the following system of equations:

\begin{align}
\dot{x_1} &= x_1 - x_1x_2 - x_2^3 + x_3(x_1^2 + x_2^2 - 1 - x_1 + x_1x_2 + x_2^3)\\
\dot{x_2} &= x_1 - x_3(x_1 - x_2 + 2x_1x_2)\\
\dot{x_3} &= (x_3 -1)(x_3 + 2x_3x_2^2 + x_3^3)
\end{align}
The set/plane $x_3 = 1$ is an invariant set. I am curious whether this invariant set contains any periodic solutions, and how I can find out. I have the following definitions to work with:

**Definition (periodic solution):** Suppose that $x = \phi(t)$ is a solution of the equation $\dot{x} = f(x)$, $x\in D\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ and suppose there exists a positive number $T$ such that $\phi(t + T) = \phi(t)$ for all $t\in\mathbb{R}$. Then $\phi(t)$ is called a periodic solution of the equation with period $T$.

**Definition (invariant set)**: Consider the equation $\dot{x} = f(x)$, $x\in D\subset \mathbb{R}^n$. The set $M\subset D$ is invariant if the solution $x(t)$ with $x(0)\in M$ is contained in $M$ for $-\infty <t < \infty$. If this property is valid only for $t\geq 0 (t\leq 0)$ then $M$ is called a positive (negative) invariant set.

**Question:** How should I find out whether the plane $x_3 =1$ contains any periodic solutions? I understand that $x_3 = 1$ is an invariant set since $\dot{x_3} = 0$ in $x_3 = 1$, but I don't really know how I should use this fact to find out whether there are any periodic solutions in $x_3 = 1$.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also write your system as
\begin{align}
\dot{x_1} &= (1-x_3)(x_1 - x_1x_2 - x_2^3) + x_3(x_1^2 + x_2^2 - 1)\\
\dot{x_2} &= (1-x_3)x_1 + x_3x_2( 1 - 2x_1)\\
\dot{x_3} &= (x_3 -1)(x_3 + 2x_3x_2^2 + x_3^3)
\end{align}
so that on the plane $x_3=1$ the system reduces to
\begin{align}
\dot{x_1} &= x_1^2 + x_2^2 - 1 \\
\dot{x_2} &= x_2( 1 - 2x_1)\\
\dot{x_3} &= 0
\end{align}
Wolfram Alpha with the command for an overview

```
streamplot[{x^2+y^2-1,y(1-2x)}, {x,-3,5}, {y,-4,4}]
```

and zoom-in

```
streamplot[{x^2+y^2-1,y(1-2x)}, {x,0.4,0.6}, {y,0.75,0.95}]
```

gives the phase portraits

[image: global view of phase portrait]
[image: zoom-in to a center point]

which looks negative for any periodic solution.

Answer (score 2):

To add on to LutzL's answer, I think we can also use some integral theorems argument.

Let $V = (x_1^2 + x_2^2 - 1, x_2(1-2x_1))$ be your vector field on the $x_3 = 1$ plane.

Then $div(V) = 2x_1 + 1 - 2x_1 = 1$.

Now suppose $\gamma$ is an integral curve of $V$ encircling some region $D$.

Then (since $\dot\gamma =V$), we get:

$0 = \int_\gamma (-V_2, V_1) \cdot\dot \gamma  = \int_D div(V) dA = area(D)$

So that there are no periodic orbits!

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Could you elaborate on the following points? Why do we have $\dot{\gamma} = V$? Why do we have $0 = area(D)$? Why does $area(D) = 0$ imply that there are no periodic solutions?

Comment: Sure! Its because $\dot\gamma = V$ is just how to write that $\gamma$ is a solution of the differential equation (the tangent vector to the curve is the vector field). IF $\gamma$ was a periodic solution, it would be a smooth closed loop surrounding some region $D$. We then get area(D) = 0 from Green's theorem. On the left we compute the line integral over $\gamma$ of the vector field $(-V_2, V_1)$ which is perpendicular to $\dot\gamma = (V_1, V_2)$ (so zero). On the right we get integral of div(V)= 1 over D, or area(D).

There are no smooth loops surrounding zero area, so no periodic orbits